# Detect 3 fingers on screen that don't move from original position iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, multi-touch

My app needs to be able to detect if the user placed 3 fingers anywhere on the screen so that it can call a method while the 3 fingers have not moved from the original position. This is my first time using multitouch in an app so can someone let me know the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer configured to require three touches (and minimal movement).

Comment: How would I define minimal movement? Is this something built in or would I have to set a boundary around each finger so that it doesn't go past a certain radius?

Comment: It's a property of the class, please do your researches before asking things. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html